# Deducing tensorial structure of a tensor

Tags: metric-tensor, tensor-calculus, lorentz-symmetry

Consider an expression of the following form:

$$I^{\mu\nu}(r) = \int d^{3}k\ \ d^{3}l\ \ \delta^{4}(r-k-l)\ (g^{\mu\nu}k\cdot{l}+k^{\nu}k^{\mu}-k^{\mu}l^{\nu})$$

$I^{\mu\nu}$ must be of the form

$$I^{\mu\nu}(r) = Ar^{\mu}r^{\nu} + B\eta^{\mu\nu},$$

where $A$ and $B$ are constants.

---

How can you determine this tensorial form of $I^{\mu\nu}$?

Comment: Are you asking why $I$ must have the form $\sim r^\mu r^\nu + \eta^{\mu\nu}$ or how to determine the coefficients $A$ and $B$?

Comment: This looks more like a Mathematics StackExchange question. Plus, this is not a homework help site. Read this: http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714/

Comment: @ yoric. I am asking why I must be of the from $r^{\mu}r^{\nu}+\eta^{\mu\nu}$.

Comment: Comments to the post (v2): 1. Please proofread! (e.g. 3 vs 4, $g$ vs $\eta$, etc). 2. More seriously, the integrand is not integrable, so regularization is necessary. 3. Consider to provide context & references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because $I$ needs to be the function of $r^\mu$ and must have superscripts ${\_}^{\mu\nu}$. So the second equation is the only possible form you can have.

Comment: why have the metric then?

Comment: You cannot use other covariant things for constant tensor $C^{\mu\nu}$  for example Kronecker delta has different indices structure i.e. $\delta^\mu{}_\nu$ so you need to write $C^{\mu\nu}=B \eta^{\mu\nu}$ when $B$ is a constant scalar.